# What Linux package is responsible for Ctrl+Shift+u1234 Unicode shortcuts?

Tags: linux, unicode

What Linux package is responsible for Ctrl+Shift+u1234 Unicode shortcuts? The whole thing stopped working lately and I don't know where to ask/fill in a bug. On Arch Linux forum they directed me to IBus, but IBus says this is not their feature

Comment: Did the shortcuts only work in some windowed environment, or also at the console?

Comment: windowed environment = desktop environment?

Comment: => Gnome. They did (but now don't) work in gnome, but never in Xterm session or plain Arch session

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is primarily provided by GTK itself (part of the built-in “gtk-im-context-simple” input module).

It *is* also provided by IBus (part of [ibusenginesimple.c](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/blob/master/src/ibusenginesimple.c#L281)). However, that implementation was broken recently while [adding a similar shortcut](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/commit/02d99aa00cb4a26a2cfb6098ea27e763e9bb2daa) for emoji mode. (Notice how `is_hex_start` is never set anymore.) It still *somewhat* works but doesn’t show visible feedback until the full character gets inserted.

(According to [issue 1944](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/1944), the developers aren’t entirely convinced that people might want to input Unicode that isn’t an emoji…)

If you have IBus installed but aren’t using IBus-specific keyboard layouts, you probably can safely switch the default module using:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-im-module gtk-im-context-simple
```

Comment: I have got installed only libibus, which is a dependency of Gnome

Comment: It was an bug in GTK, you were right